# Iteration loop through nested dictionary - stoping at second

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, iteration, openpyxl

I've thought 2nd hour and I don't know why error appears.
Error said that loop cannot find second stage of dictionary.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
book = load_workbook('OBS.xlsx')
zakladkaall = book.get_sheet_by_name('ALL')

licznik = 1
liczkolumny = 1

materialproduction = {
    licznik : {liczkolumny : ""}
}

for wiersz in range(2, zakladkaall.max_row):
    for kolumna in "ABCDEFGHI":
        komorka = "{}{}".format(kolumna, wiersz)
        wartosckomorki = zakladkaall[komorka].value
        materialproduction[licznik][liczkolumny] = wartosckomorki

        if liczkolumny < 9:
            liczkolumny += 1
            print(licznik)
            print(liczkolumny)
        else:
            liczkolumny = 1
            licznik += 1
            print(licznik)

print(materialproduction[licznik][liczkolumny])
```

Loop should made dictionary like this:
materialproduction[1][1]
.
.
.
materialproduction[1][9]
materialproduction[2][1]
.
.
.
materialproduction[2][9]

etc, but there is problem when "licznik" (first stage) has increased number to "2"...
Can you help me?

Comment: `komorka = "{}{}".format(kolumna, wiersz)` is unnecessary openpyxl provides a programmatic interface for accessing cells. Please read the introduction in the **official** documentation more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
materialproduction[key1][key2] = value
```

Will attempt to look up the value of materialproduction[key1] and then add the key2-value pair to that result.  However '2' is not a key that exists in materialproduction. So you will get a KeyError on that look up.

What you need to do is add a dictionary for each licznik key.  For example add the following before materialproduction[licznik][liczkolumny] = wartosckomorki:

```
if liczkolumny == 1:
    materialproduction[licznik] = {}
```

A cleaner way to do this is to use a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

materialproduction = defaultdict(dict)
```

If a key does not exist, instead of erroring a dictionary will be used as the result, which is what you are after.